# C# equivalent of C++ ostream::tellp for size limit on diskette

Tags: c#, c++, streamwriter, ostream

Is there a C# equivalent for StreamWriter of the C++ ostream::tellp? I am porting over some old C++ code to C#, but the client still wants to keep using diskettes (read: old equipment), so I need to find a way to find the file pointer position or to find how much I've written to disk already.

Below is the method that I've created so far:

```
 private bool isDisketteBoundary(ref StreamWriter swOutput, int nCurrentDisketteNo) {
      // Get current file pointer position
      // long filePosition = nOStream.tellp(); <-- C++ code
      long filePosition = 0; // <-- needs to change to find file pointer position

      // Valid?
      if(filePosition != -1) {
           // Is the new size over a boundary?
           float numDiskettes = (float)((float)filePosition / (float)Constants.DisketteSize);
           int disketteCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(numDiskettes));

           // Is the diskette count larger than the current index?
           return (nCurrentDisketteNo < disketteCount) ? true : false;
      }
      else {
           throw new Exception("Unable to get file pointer from StreamWriter");
      }
 }
```

Comment: Upgrade your client then! ;-)

Comment: @Kos At the amount they pay my company, I think that might be a bad idea. :P

Comment: The real name is "floppy disk" =)

Comment: @Calvin1602 To clarify, its the 3.5" not the 5.25" or 8" disks. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
swOutput.BaseStream.Position
```

see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx .